# Where to put native dependencies when creating NuGet packages

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

Using .NET Core 2.2, I want to create a NuGet package with native dependencies for different platforms (win-x64, linux-x64, linux-arm). The dependencies are pre-built DLLs/SOs using a C compiler.

I've successfully created the NuGet package with all dependencies put into the runtimes folder in a subfolder for each platform.

My problem is that I have a unit test project in the same solution and I need the native dependencies to be copied to the output folder for the unit tests to run successfully.

The question is where in the source to put the native dependencies so that the correct one is copied to the output folder when I build or publish for a specific platform. Also, what do I need to add to the .csproj file to achieve this?